# convert this pl sql script to stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert this to a Oracle procedure so that I can use it in SSRS for reporting. SSRS can't execute the script so have to convert it to a procedure. Or maybe convert to a single select statement if possible. The purpose is to return a data set so it can consumed by SSRS but SSRS work trough oracle client driver and can only understand simple statement (single select) or stored procedures. I know very little about pl sql. P.S: Oracle 9i.

There are 3 parameters (parameter 1, 2,3 in the code below) need to be implemented in the proc as well.

```
    CREATE TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount(
    week_id INT
    ,web_discount_code VARCHAR2(100)
    ,promotion_type VARCHAR2(100)
    ,AS01 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS02 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS03 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS04 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS05 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS06 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS07 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS08 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS09 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS10 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS11 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS12 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS13 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS14 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS15 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS16 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS17 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS18 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS19 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS20 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB01 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB04 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB05 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KBNW NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KBDN NUMBER(12,6)
    ,adjusted_amount NUMBER(12,6)
    );

    DECLARE l_to_date DATE;

      CURSOR c1 IS 
        SELECT week_id, from_date , to_date
          FROM ggcus_calendar
        WHERE year_id = 7 --[parameter1]
        ORDER BY week_id;

    BEGIN

     FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
      l_to_date := r1.to_date + 1;

      INSERT INTO ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount
      SELECT  
                R1.week_id,
                disc.web_discount_id web_discount_code,
                hdr.description promotion_type,

                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS01' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS01,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS02' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS02,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS03' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS03,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS04' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS04,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS05' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS05,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS06' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS06,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS07' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS07,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS08' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS08,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS09' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS09,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS10' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS10,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS11' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS11,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS12' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS12,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS13' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS13,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS14' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS14,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS15' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS15,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS16' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS16,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS17' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS17,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS18' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS18,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS19' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS19,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS20' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS20,            
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB01' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB01,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB04' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB04,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB05' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB05,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KBNW' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KBNW,
                (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KBDN' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KBDN,
                (DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)) adjusted_amount
         FROM   oe_order_headers_all ooh,
                oe_order_lines_all ool,
                oe_transaction_types_tl oot,
                oe_transaction_types_all trx_type,
                oe_price_adjustments opa,
                mtl_system_items_b msi,
                ar_vat_tax_all_b vat,
                mtl_categories_b ctg,
                mtl_item_categories mic,
                mtl_category_sets_tl mcs,
                hz_cust_accounts hca,
                hz_parties hp,
                ggcus_web_discount_mappings disc,
                qp_list_headers_tl hdr
        WHERE       1 = 1
                AND trx_type.attribute1 = 'INT'
                AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
                AND ooh.ordered_DATE >= '18-MAR-2012' -- parameter 2
                AND ooh.ordered_DATE < '19-MAR-2012' -- parameter 3
                AND ooh.order_type_id = trx_type.transaction_type_id
                AND trx_type.transaction_type_id = oot.transaction_type_id
                AND oot.language = 'US'
                AND ooh.flow_status_code != 'CANCELLED'
                AND ooh.booked_flag = 'Y'
                AND ool.flow_status_code != 'CANCELLED'
                AND ool.booked_flag = 'Y'
                AND msi.organization_id = 101
                AND msi.inventory_item_id = ool.inventory_item_id
                AND ooh.ordered_date BETWEEN NVL (vat.start_date, SYSDATE)
                                         AND  NVL (vat.end_date, SYSDATE)
                AND ool.tax_code = vat.tax_code
                AND mcs.category_set_name = 'GGI Inventory'
                AND mic.category_set_id = mcs.category_set_id
                AND ctg.category_id = mic.category_id
                AND mcs.language = 'US'
                AND mic.inventory_item_id = ool.inventory_item_id
                AND mic.organization_id = 101
                AND opa.line_id = ool.line_id
                AND opa.list_line_type_code = 'DIS'
                AND opa.attribute1 = disc.web_discount_id
                AND opa.applied_flag = 'Y'
                AND opa.header_id = ooh.header_id
                AND hca.cust_account_id = ooh.sold_to_org_id
                AND hca.party_id = hp.party_id
                AND hdr.name = disc.modifier_name
                AND ooh.ordered_date >= r1.from_date
                AND ooh.ordered_date < l_to_date;

         COMMIT;

       END LOOP;
    END;

    SELECT
         Week_Id
        ,Web_Discount_Code
        ,Promotion_Type
        ,SUM(AS01)
        ,SUM(AS02)
        ,SUM(AS03)
        ,SUM(AS04)
        ,SUM(AS05)
        ,SUM(AS06)
        ,SUM(AS07)
        ,SUM(AS08)
        ,SUM(AS09)
        ,SUM(AS10)
        ,SUM(AS11)
        ,SUM(AS12)
        ,SUM(AS13)
        ,SUM(AS14)
        ,SUM(AS15)
        ,SUM(AS16)
        ,SUM(AS17)
        ,SUM(AS18)
        ,SUM(AS19)
        ,SUM(AS20)
        ,SUM(KB01)
        ,SUM(KB04)
        ,SUM(KB05)
        ,SUM(KBNW)
        ,SUM(KBDN)
        ,SUM(adjusted_amount)
    FROM ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount
    GROUP BY Week_Id, Web_Discount_Code, Promotion_Type
    ;


    DROP TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount;
```

Comment: Why are you using a 'temporary' table for this, rather than just selecting from the real tables? That would make your life easier, and would probably run faster as well.

Comment: This script was done by someone ages ago. And I am not a Oracle developer. I just need to do reporting based on this script. That's why I am asking can it be converted to a simple statement.

Answer (score 0):

Before you read the code - notice that in there you run an sql - which you don't do anything with.

What I wrote over here is the generic way to do it- it will not compile - since you'll have to edit the string there on differ lines (each line would end with "'", and will start with "|| '".

Notice the "execute immediate" for the DDL's.

Read about global temporary table - it would make your life much simpler for this code!!

IT IS NOT ADVISED TO CREATE AND DROP TABLES WITHIN A PL/SQL!!!
IF YOU GOT TO DO IT - 90% YOU'RE DOING SOMETHING WRONG

you're code would look like that:

```
create procedure procname IS
  l_to_date DATE; 

  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT week_id, from_date , to_date
      FROM ggcus_calendar
    WHERE year_id = 7 --[parameter1]
    ORDER BY week_id;
BEGIN

execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount(
week_id INT
,web_discount_code VARCHAR2(100)
,promotion_type VARCHAR2(100)
,AS01 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS02 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS03 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS04 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS05 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS06 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS07 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS08 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS09 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS10 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS11 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS12 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS13 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS14 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS15 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS16 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS17 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS18 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS19 NUMBER(12,6)
,AS20 NUMBER(12,6)
,KB01 NUMBER(12,6)
,KB04 NUMBER(12,6)
,KB05 NUMBER(12,6)
,KBNW NUMBER(12,6)
,KBDN NUMBER(12,6)
,adjusted_amount NUMBER(12,6)
);';


 FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
  l_to_date := r1.to_date + 1;

  INSERT INTO ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount
  SELECT  
            R1.week_id,
            disc.web_discount_id web_discount_code,
            hdr.description promotion_type,

            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS01' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS01,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS02' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS02,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS03' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS03,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS04' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS04,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS05' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS05,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS06' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS06,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS07' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS07,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS08' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS08,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS09' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS09,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS10' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS10,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS11' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS11,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS12' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS12,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS13' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS13,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS14' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS14,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS15' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS15,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS16' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS16,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS17' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS17,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS18' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS18,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS19' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS19,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'AS20' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) AS20,            
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB01' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB01,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB04' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB04,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KB05' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KB05,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KBNW' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KBNW,
            (CASE WHEN ctg.segment1|| ctg.segment2 = 'KBDN' THEN DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)  ELSE 0 END) KBDN,
            (DECODE (ool.line_category_code,'RETURN', opa.adjusted_amount * -1,opa.adjusted_amount)) adjusted_amount
     FROM   oe_order_headers_all ooh,
            oe_order_lines_all ool,
            oe_transaction_types_tl oot,
            oe_transaction_types_all trx_type,
            oe_price_adjustments opa,
            mtl_system_items_b msi,
            ar_vat_tax_all_b vat,
            mtl_categories_b ctg,
            mtl_item_categories mic,
            mtl_category_sets_tl mcs,
            hz_cust_accounts hca,
            hz_parties hp,
            ggcus_web_discount_mappings disc,
            qp_list_headers_tl hdr
    WHERE       1 = 1
            AND trx_type.attribute1 = 'INT'
            AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
            AND ooh.ordered_DATE >= '18-MAR-2012' -- parameter 2
            AND ooh.ordered_DATE < '19-MAR-2012' -- parameter 3
            AND ooh.order_type_id = trx_type.transaction_type_id
            AND trx_type.transaction_type_id = oot.transaction_type_id
            AND oot.language = 'US'
            AND ooh.flow_status_code != 'CANCELLED'
            AND ooh.booked_flag = 'Y'
            AND ool.flow_status_code != 'CANCELLED'
            AND ool.booked_flag = 'Y'
            AND msi.organization_id = 101
            AND msi.inventory_item_id = ool.inventory_item_id
            AND ooh.ordered_date BETWEEN NVL (vat.start_date, SYSDATE)
                                     AND  NVL (vat.end_date, SYSDATE)
            AND ool.tax_code = vat.tax_code
            AND mcs.category_set_name = 'GGI Inventory'
            AND mic.category_set_id = mcs.category_set_id
            AND ctg.category_id = mic.category_id
            AND mcs.language = 'US'
            AND mic.inventory_item_id = ool.inventory_item_id
            AND mic.organization_id = 101
            AND opa.line_id = ool.line_id
            AND opa.list_line_type_code = 'DIS'
            AND opa.attribute1 = disc.web_discount_id
            AND opa.applied_flag = 'Y'
            AND opa.header_id = ooh.header_id
            AND hca.cust_account_id = ooh.sold_to_org_id
            AND hca.party_id = hp.party_id
            AND hdr.name = disc.modifier_name
            AND ooh.ordered_date >= r1.from_date
            AND ooh.ordered_date < l_to_date;

     COMMIT;

   END LOOP;

SELECT
     Week_Id
    ,Web_Discount_Code
    ,Promotion_Type
    ,SUM(AS01)
    ,SUM(AS02)
    ,SUM(AS03)
    ,SUM(AS04)
    ,SUM(AS05)
    ,SUM(AS06)
    ,SUM(AS07)
    ,SUM(AS08)
    ,SUM(AS09)
    ,SUM(AS10)
    ,SUM(AS11)
    ,SUM(AS12)
    ,SUM(AS13)
    ,SUM(AS14)
    ,SUM(AS15)
    ,SUM(AS16)
    ,SUM(AS17)
    ,SUM(AS18)
    ,SUM(AS19)
    ,SUM(AS20)
    ,SUM(KB01)
    ,SUM(KB04)
    ,SUM(KB05)
    ,SUM(KBNW)
    ,SUM(KBDN)
    ,SUM(adjusted_amount)
FROM ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount
GROUP BY Week_Id, Web_Discount_Code, Promotion_Type
;


execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount';
end;
```

With temporary tables you'll have to run this once:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount(
    week_id INT
    ,web_discount_code VARCHAR2(100)
    ,promotion_type VARCHAR2(100)
    ,AS01 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS02 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS03 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS04 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS05 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS06 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS07 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS08 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS09 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS10 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS11 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS12 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS13 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS14 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS15 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS16 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS17 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS18 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS19 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,AS20 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB01 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB04 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KB05 NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KBNW NUMBER(12,6)
    ,KBDN NUMBER(12,6)
    ,adjusted_amount NUMBER(12,6)
    ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

and than your procedure will not have to change at all (just add "create procedure procname is" before it.

And all the data will be in the table after running the procedure until you commit or delete it manually.

The huge benefit of temporary table - is that it is private for the session.

multiple sessions can run it in parallel - and each session will get only their results, while the session that did not run the procedure will not see any records in it.

bottom line - read about temporary tables...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE ggcus.ggcus_tmp_imo_discount( part doesn't compile. But I don't mind if it's a physical or temp table got created. So I can live with the original code. I only need to convert it to a proc. In your proc, is there only one parameter (year_id)? I need three, but I guess the year_id can be calculated from start and end date. So two parameters: start and end date. Again, I don't know PL SQL, I am a BI developer and only try to resolve this because our oracle guy is in hospital and will be for a while.